# Mock Access to Outer Object From Local Inner Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class with a local inner class in one of its methods:

```
public class Outer {
    String hello = "hello";

    public void myMethod() {

        class Inner {
            public void myInnerMethod() {
                System.out.println(hello);         
            }
        }

        [...really slow routine...]

        (new Inner()).myInnerMethod();
    }
}
```

I would like to test the `myInnerMethod()`. So I instantiate the local inner class using reflection and call the `myInnerMethod()` on it.

```
public void test() {
    Object inner = Class.forName("Outer$Inner").newInstance();
    inner.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myInnerMethod").invoke(inner); // hello will be null
}
```

But when `myInnerMethod()` accesses `hello`, which is in the scope of the Outer class, it is `null`.

Is there a way to mock or otherwise provide hello to `myInnerMethod()`?

I know I could refactor my code by extracting the inner class or just test the public methods of Outer. But is there still a way to do it?

Comment: Well, you'd need an instance of `Outer` to access `hello` anyways, so why not create an instance of `Outer` in your test as well? Btw, I'd doubt you get the NPE because `hello` is null but you probably get it because the reference to `Outer` is null (you could think of the access to `hello` as actually being `Outer.this.hello`).

Comment: show full myMethod implementation.. how the Inner is instantiated then invoked

Comment: thanks @Thomas. I altered the comment line in the code

Comment: done @MaciejKowalski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make some small refactoring before being able to verify the inner behavior:

**1)** Create a package level method that would contain the code invoked from within the `myInnerMEthod`:

```
public class Outer {
    String hello = "hello";

    public void myMethod() {

        class Inner {
            public void myInnerMethod() {
                Outer.this.printHello(hello);    // !!! change here     
            }
        }

        [...really slow routine...]

        (new Inner()).myInnerMethod();
    }

    void printHello(String hello){/* */}   // !! add this
}
```

**2)** Spy on the `Outer` class and verify the `printHello` has been called with the hello instance variable:

```
public void test() {
    // Arrange
    Outer outerSpy = spy(new Outer());
    doNothing().when(outerSpy).printHello(anyString()); // optional

    // Act
    outer.myMethod();

    // Assert
    verify(outerSpy).printHello("hello");
}
```

Comment: This solution tests the outer method and moves logic to the outer class. It is not what I would ideally want.

Comment: You should not be testing that inner class behavior on itself as it is equivalent of unit testing behavior of a private method. You should not do that. Test public behavior of a SUT, not its inner workings

Comment: Looking at my actual code further, I realized that the logic I actually wanted to test would be better placed in a new method of the outer class. So your solution makes perfect sense.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped you out